# How to ensureIndex in sails js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I've written an application using sails.js framework.
http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation
I cannot manage to run an ensureindex in the controller.
What is the way to run an ensureIndex query in sails.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.native()` method to run any [native Mongo command](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/contents.html) in Sails.  In this case, assuming a model called `User`, it would be:

```
User.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex("username",callback)
});
```

Alhough in most cases you probably want to do things like `ensureIndex` in the Mongo console when setting up your DB, not in realtime in your app...